# Revert webkit-appearance for input of type number

Tags: css

In my css which I use in the whole application I have this code:

```
input[type=number]::-webkit-inner-spin-button, 
input[type=number]::-webkit-outer-spin-button {
    -webkit-appearance: none;
    -moz-appearance: textfield;
    margin: 0; 
}
```

With that style the arrows from the inputs of type number are hidden in my whole app. But in one page, I have an input element with type number and a class "numberInGrid" and I want the arrows to be shown for the .numberInGrid elements. How do I do this?

Answer (score 0):

appearance css default value in normal use it for `.numberInGrid`

```
.numberInGrid{
  appearance:normal;
  -moz-appearance:normal;
  -webkit-appearance:normal;
}
```

Comment: I get a warning that normal is an invalid value for -webkit-appearance.